# Helloworld in symbian

Tags: c++, symbian

I am a j2me developer but now I have to develop an application for Symbian in C++. I am completely new to it.

I installed Perl, Symbian S60 5th edition and Carbide.c++, and started to create the 'helloworld' application as guided in this documentation:
http://library.forum.nokia.com/index...6502C151E.html.

I get 2 errors during building of the application

The errors are:

1) `undefined identifier 'KGeneral_Information' HellowordAppUi.cpp /Helloword/src line 206 C/C++ Problem`

2) `the file 'Helloword_0xE0C8D323.hlp.hrh' cannot be opened HellowordAppUi.cpp /Helloword/src line 22 C/C++ Problem`

Warning are:

1) `#warning "Please see comment about help and UID3..." HellowordAppUi.cpp /Helloword/src line 193 C/C++ Problem`

2) `preprocessor #warning directive HellowordAppUi.cpp /Helloword/src line 193 C/C++ Problem`

I am not able to understand why it is happening. The workspace is in same drive as the SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your build file, comment the line after PRJ_MMPFILES.

This happens because application help fine is not defined.